# Can't use WCF service client via Class Library

Tags: c#, wcf

I've created a simple WCF service on http://localhost:20999/WCFService

**I can create a client to call web service method with Console Application, but got an error when create a WCF client in class library.**

> Could not find default endpoint element that references contract ...

- VS2010
- Test client is compiled in x64

---

Then I've created a simple test app, contains ConsoleApp and ClassLib. Both project add the WCF service as a service reference.

[image: Client solution]

Class 1 contains Test function

```
public void Test()
    {
        ServiceReference2.TSI7WCFServiceClient client = new ServiceReference2.TSI7WCFServiceClient();
        Console.WriteLine(client.Invoke("123", "456"));
    }
```

And ConsoleApp Program.cs

```
    Console.WriteLine("---- Call WCF directly ----");
    ServiceReference1.TSI7WCFServiceClient client = new ServiceReference1.TSI7WCFServiceClient();
    String result = client.Invoke("Test", "This is Parameter");
    Console.WriteLine("Result = {0}", result);
    client.Close();

    Console.WriteLine("\n\n---- Call WCF via ClassLib ----");
    ClassLibrary1.Class1 clientLib = new ClassLibrary1.Class1();
    clientLib.Test();
```

And here is result
[image: Console result]

Comment: This looks like a configuration issue, not a programming issue. Have you followed up the hint given by the error message?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure you copy the endpoint information from the app.config of the class project to the app.config of the console project.

Comment: I'm quite new for WCF, btw, if i use namespace ServiceReference1 in ClassLib, same as Console lib, both of them will work.

Comment: The service reference refers to an endpoint configuration in the app.config.  If that end point doesn't exist in the app.config or is there with a different name it won't find it.  So you have to make sure the bindings and endpoint exist in both projects.  I'm not sure why you would call the same WCF service in two different projects though.  It'd be best to make it one or the other.

So all of that being said, yes, you'll need to manually copy that information from app.config to app.config.

Comment: I want to use WCF service in classLib project only, But this is just a test project to solve the problem.

Btw, it's work, thanks a lot. I have to add endpoint from ClassLib to ConsoleApp.